# Send data to USB GPIO device on Ubuntu

Tags: c, usb, driver, linux-device-driver, gpio

I use a [USB GPIO device](http://numato.com/16-channel-usb-gpio-module). When it was connected to PC, it created a file that was named "/dev/ttyACM0". I want to send data using termios.
I run

```
int fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
```

in C code, but it didn't work.
What should it be?

**UPDATE**

After USB device was connected to PC, I run `dmesg` command on terminal. It showed device information such as product, manufacturer, idVendor, idProduct etc.

**UPDATE 2**
My error was "no file or directory". So I tried [this method](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,152105.0.html) for solution. I run `sudo stty crtscts -F /dev/ttyACM0`.I rewrite open port via `int fd = open("/dev/tty1", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);` I recompiled  and run my code. New runtime error is "/dev/tty1 : Permission denied"

Comment: Since you have created a new (previously unknown) device name, you also need to create the kernel driver for that device.

Comment: Should I write it? Is the driver insufficient?

Comment: my device is here http://numato.com/16-channel-usb-gpio-module

Comment: @user3629249 From the description given, the device is identifying itself as a USB CDC serial device. No additional driver is necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What happens when you try it?

Comment: I got an error, no such file or directory.

Comment: Is that error reported by the shell as a result of trying to execute your program, or the *errno* from the `open()`?  Instead of us having to extract this info from you, instead you should try to provide as much as possible voluntarily.

Comment: ok. I will be more careful. It is runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just don't have permission to write to that device, that's why it worked with sudo.
 
You just have to add your user account to the appropriate group, which probably is `tty` for `/dev/ttyACMx` (this depends on the distro though).

Or you could change the permissions of that device with `sudo chmod 644 /dev/ttyACM0`.

You may find this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Groups) helpful.

Comment: You should **not** change the permissions of a device but instead run the program with enough privileges.

Comment: Or he could just change the RW permissions for his user account only. (I edited the suggested permissions) But yes the best solution is what you said.

Answer (score 2):

For "permission denied" error, you should run `$ sudo ./exe`. I did, it worked fine!

Comment: That is not the preferred solution.  Usually all you have to do is *add* your *username* to the *group* that owns the device (usually "dialout" for tty devices).